# How to recognize which activity call fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

In my app I have a fragment with map (Google Maps API v2) which I use when user is **not log-in** - ActivityA and when the user **is log in** - ActivityB. I add some markers when user is not log in and when the user is, I take points from JSON. How to recognize which activity "call" the fragment?

**Fragment**

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
                googleMap = mMap;

                //when the user is not log in
                for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(result.get(i).getLat(), result.get(i).getLng())).title(result.get(i).getTitle());
                    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
                }

                //add here code when user is log in

                //show image of the point in dialog
                googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                        Log.i("MARKER", marker.getPosition().toString());
                        showAlertDialog(marker);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

my idea is put some boolean value like **userIsLogin** and then check true/false and get List depends on bool value. 
Is there any better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if(getActivity() instanceof ActivityA)
do activity a stuff
if(getActivity() instanceof ActivityB)
do activity b stuff

Answer (score 1):

If you need stable and universal solution you can write utility class to determine what activity is returned by getActivity() method in fragment. Here is an example:

```
public class ActivityRecognizer {
    public static final String MY_ACTIVITY = "my_activity";

    public String getActivityType(Activity activity) {
        if (activity == null) return NONE;
        else if (activity instanceof MyActivity) return MY_ACTIVITY;
    }
}
```

And then you just check needed constant string in your fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor in fragment and pass some boolean from activity. For better message passing you can create interface and implement it in activity. Provide interface instance(which is activity) in fragment and from fragment access function of activity using interface instance to get its value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get activity from fragment using getActivity() method.